# How can i post data in to a textarea?

Tags: php, html, xhtml

```html
Area <input type="text" name="area" size="15" maxlength="25" value="<?php echo $data2['area'] ?>" /><br /><br />
Description <br /><br /> <textarea rows="8" cols="50" name="description" value="<?php echo $data2['description']?>"></textarea> <br /> <br />
```

I can post data into the input text from the database but its not working for the text area, this page is for allowing users to update there ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `textarea` no need `value` attribute. Bellow code:

```
<textarea rows="8" cols="50" name="description"><?php echo $data2['description']?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<texarea>` HTML element does not have *value* attribute. Just put your PHP code between `<textarea></textarea>` like this:

```
<textarea><?php echo $something ?></textarea>
```